# how to add one more connection to a model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, assign

For example, I have 2 models:

ticket.rb

```
belongs_to :user
```

user.rb

```
has_many :tickets, dependent: :destroy
```

In the table Tickets I have

```
t.integer  "user_id"
```

This all works fine. But what if I wish to add a new field assignee_id, and that should be a user from the same table Users?
I can add just a field assigne_id and populate it with user_id I need, but I would like to use a construction like @ticket.assignee.name like I use for @ticket.user.name. Please could you help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do, Rails allows you to pass bunch of parameters to `belongs_to`. In your case, You need to specify the `foreign key` and the `class name` of the association.

---

This is how you can join `assignee` to `user` table

```
#ticket.rb
belongs_to :assignee, foreign_key: "assignee_id", class_name: "User"
```

source: [edgeguides.rubyonrails.org](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to)

source: [api.rubyonrails.org](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#method-i-belongs_to-label-Options)

Comment: Thank you! Somehow your line did not work, but worked after I wrote it like this:   belongs_to :assignee, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "assignee_id"